# Eclipse, gradle Dependencies (persisted) missing libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jar, dependencies

I have the following error, in Eclipse buildpath:

[image]

I already tried to: delete Gradle cache and to select refresh All without success

[image]

Comment: You can try re importing the project..

Comment: tried last night and worked, probably a bug with Eclipse / Gradle!

Answer (score 0):

Re-importing the project in Eclipse fixed the issue